# GC not delete object from array after removing reference

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I've got class **Shape**:

```
private int refcount = 0;
private static long counter = 0;
private final long id = counter++;
Shape () {
    System.out.println("Create "+ this);
}

public void addRef() { refcount++; }
public void dispose() {
    if (--refcount == 0)
        System.out.println("Delete " + this);
}

@Override
public String toString() { return "Shape "+ id; }

@Override
public void finalize() {
    if (refcount == 0)
        System.out.println("Finalize correctly " + this);
}
```

and second class **Container**:

```
private Shape shape;
private static long counter = 0;
private final long id = counter++;
Container (Shape shape) {
    this.shape = shape;
    this.shape.addRef();
    System.out.println("Create " + this );
}


public void dispose() {
    System.out.println("Delete " + this);
    shape.dispose();
}

@Override
public String toString() { return "Container "+ id; }

@Override   
public void finalize() { System.out.println("Finalize container!"); }
```

This is my simple main code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Start");
    Shape sh = new Shape();
    Container[] cont = { new Container(sh), new Container(sh), new Container(sh) };
    for (Container c : cont)  
        c.dispose();           
    cont = null;
    System.gc();
    System.out.println("Finish");
}
```

I would like to know, why I didn't get comment "Finalize container!"? When I delete line:

```
    for (Container c : cont)
        c.dispose();
```

program working correctly - I got 3 times comment "Finalize container".

Comment: Uh, you still have a reference to the shape.  Why are you dealing with this anyway?  Anything having to do with finalization is a pretty decisive indicator your code is problematic.

Comment: Why do you need such precise 'control' over your references? In the vast majority of cases you can - and should - just let the GC look after that, and not try to thwart it, e.g. by calling `System.gc()` (probably ever)

Comment: I know, but i don't understand why i have reference? I also know that finalization is often problematic, but i don't know any other way to check if my objects were deleted.

Comment: But why do you need to know? Concentrate on writing good code, which is hard enough already. The VM and GC are very capable and better at dealing with memory than 95% of Java devs - unless you're working on real-time trading applications, perhaps. You can save tonnes of code ^^. Besides, if you do detect memory problems later, Profilers are cheap and easy to use.

Comment: @AndrewRegan JVM and GC working very good and i don't want improve them. I wanted to see whether i correct manage references. If results were the same i don't worry about it, but different results suprised me

Comment: Sure, I understand, but my point is that unless you have a complex case, you shouldn't try. You'll likely make things harder and worse, and that the results may be misleading. Enjoy the fact that Java is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

System.gc() does not guarantee a full gc, it is just a best effort suggestion to the JVM, do not count on it.